# Git creating directory in repository [Codespaces]

Tags: eclipse, git, git-commit, git-bash

My Setup: I do the  local commits in Eclipse IDE itself. My local repositories resides within the workspace as well.
Somehow I couldn't do remote commits using Eclipse so I just did, thus I've been using git bash to do remote commits to codespaces.com

```
git remote add origin git@codespaces.com:acct_name/repo_name
git push origin master
```

This has served me well so far.

Now I created another repository, let's say `repo_foo`.
For this repository, I want to place multiple directories(projects) inside it. I don't really need the codespaces `Projects` here.
I just want to be able to do this.

```
git remote add origin git@codespaces.com:acct_name/repo_foo/proj_1 
(currently this gives no repository in path error)
```

So the repo structure should looks like this.

```
repo_foo
 - proj_1
   -src
 - proj_2
   -src
   -lib
```

etc.

Any ideas for this?

Answer (score 0):

> Now I created another repository,let's say repo_foo. For this repository, I want to place multiple directories (projects) inside it.
>   I dont really need the codespaces "Projects" here. I just want to be
>   able to do this.

So you want to have nested git repositories in other git repositories? It’s unclear what your final goal is. Perhaps [`git submodules`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) would serve your needs?  Submodules are basically other repositories cloned into another git repository.  So let’s say you have a main project, but you also have a repo for a great library you want to use. You can add the library as a submodule & refer it to the main project.  That way if you make changes to the library, the projects that have that library as a submodule can be automagically updated. Quite powerful concept if you need that.

The problem from my perspective is you are convolving the concept of a directory & a repository into one thing.  So when you do the following:

```
git remote add origin git@codespaces.com:acct_name/repo_foo/proj_1
```

You are saying, “Go into this repo. And create another repo in that repo.”

There will be no `origin` of `git@codespaces.com:acct_name/repo_foo/proj_1` since the parent repo of `git@codespaces.com:acct_name/repo_foo` already exists.

What you need to do is setup a repo for each project & decide on a naming scheme.  Something like:

- repo_foo_proj_1
- repo_foo_proj_2
- etc…

And your `git remote add origin` command would be:

```
git remote add origin git@codespaces.com:acct_name/repo_foo_proj_1
git remote add origin git@codespaces.com:acct_name/repo_foo_proj_2
etc…
```

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize git in a folder, all the sub folders are auto tracked. When working with multiple projects or folders, where each should be tracked independently. You should keep them at the same level.

```
--home
  --Workspace
    --project1
    --project2
    --project3
```

In case you initialize git accidently at workspace, when you check `git status`, it includes all the the files and folders underneath to be tracked. When you perform `git remote add origin`, config file under .git/config is added with a remote url which is used for push and pull operations. So if you initialize repo_foo and provide the `remote add`, you cannot perform the same actions under proj_1. It's automatically being tracked and all the push/pull operations will use the path present in `repo_foo/.git/config` file.